# Handling .csv in python

Tags: python, performance, search, optimization

I'm new to python and I'm doing a little project so I can learn more.

I want to read in a .csv file of arbitrary size, file A, but only store the 3rd column of every row into a list, list X. I then want to check every row of another .csv file of arbitrary size, file B, against every value in list 1 there are any matches. File B will always have around 200 times as many lines as file A with 32 elements on each line, but I'm only interested in checking for matches in file B's 11th column. When I've found a match, I use the index of that row to add the entire row from file B to a new 2d list, list Y, containing all 32 elements. I've managed to read in both files to their own lists and created a new list containing the 11th element(s) from file B's list, and I've also managed to output a .txt with all the sorted data by simply checking every element for a match, but it outputs in this format:

```
['data1','data2','data3',...]
['data4','data5','data6',...]
```

I'd like to export list Y to a .csv file, but when I tried using pandas:

```
df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\doobie_dude\onedrive\desktop\proj\results.csv')
df.to_csv(r'C:\Users\doobie_dude\onedrive\desktop\proj\final_product.csv')
```

I got these errors in my terminal:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 122, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\doobie_dude\onedrive\desktop\proj\results.csv')
  File "/home/doobie_dude/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/home/doobie_dude/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 452, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/home/doobie_dude/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 946, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/home/doobie_dude/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1178, in _make_engine    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/home/doobie_dude/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2008, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'C:\\Users\\doobie_dude\\onedrive\\desktop\\data\\results.csv'
```

I installed pandas by typing 'pip3 install pandas' in my terminal. Is there an installation error? I frankly don't know how to interpret the stuff terminal spits back at me. I'd also like to know if there's a way to check for matches in-between my data sets quicker.

```
for i in range(len(rawList)):
    for j in range(len(list Y)):
        if(myZipList[i]==everyOtherZip[j]):
            matchZipIndices.append(int(j))
            ufResultsList.append(rawList[j])
```

I'm using lots of lists and I have no one to teach me best practice other than the gods at stackoverflow. Help me get gains pls

Answer (score 0):

Pandas seems to be installed properly otherwise you would get a `ModuleNotFoundError` error https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ModuleNotFoundError

Your error stack indicates that the python code is unable to find the file.

What is surprising is that you are asking to read the file:

`r'C:\Users\doobie_dude\onedrive\desktop\proj\results.csv'`

but the error mentions the file:

`'C:\\Users\\doobie_dude\\onedrive\\desktop\\data\\results.csv'`

You should probably check your filesystem and you could have a shenanigan with symbolic links.

---

Concerning the issue with you check could you give all the definition of your variable in the code sample. How are `rawList`, `Y`, `myZipList`, `everyOtherZip`, `matchZipIndices`, `ufResultsList`, `rawList` initialized ?